# app rejected.how to track user non-renewing subscription

Tags: objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

i developed an app for on Online Magazine with non-renewing subscription type.

Apple Developer Guide say :

" it's not appropriate to track the subscription using the UDID or the Apple Store ID.
**The subscription should be tracked with an external server** that you should provide in order to deliver subscription to multiple devices.
Additionally, please keep in mind that it is not appropriate to force user registration to meet this requirement; such user registration must be made optional. "

and i recently had my app rejected by apple for those reasons:

```
11.6: Content subscriptions using IAP must last a minimum of 7 days and be available to the user from all of their iOS devices
17.2: Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected
```

so..
**how can i TRACK users and also user subscription on my Server** in order to assign the right expiration day for the magazines? 
like apple said here 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html (into Server Product Model)

i think i had rejected my app because i force the user to put a valid e-mail on my server in order to track his subscription.

i'm sure some one went into that..did anyone had the same problems?

Comment: You might find my question has some insight into this as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492898/how-to-support-multiple-devices-with-non-renewing-in-app-purchase/9500185#9500185

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try this approach:

On the first run, the app registers with your server and get back a unique_token. Store it on server and client side.
Upon every purchase submit to your server the unique_token and store the association between unique_token and the purchased product.
If the user register with your service (login & pass) send also the unique_token and associate the product id to the user directly.

When you design your database keep in mind that a user can buy 2 different products on 2 different devices, register on one of them and then login on the other one.

Pros:

- Registration is not mandatory.
- You don't need to use UDID.

Cons:

- Way more complex. (thx Apple)
- If a user deletes the app without registering all the purchases are lost. However some workarounds might be possible (ex submit to the server also the mac address of WiFi/Bluetooth interface [I have no idea if any private api is needed or it's again someother apple guideline] )

Comment: tnx Cesar. may be a solution.

Comment: But What if i use a Coded UDID instead mac address of WiFi interface. You think apple is reject again the app? tnx

Comment: Well, afaik UDID [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier] have been deprecated in iOS5 :)

Comment: I don't see how this would work — how can the second device become tied to the same account as the first without requiring a registration?

Comment: Sync between devices requires registartion, however the app doesn't require registration in order to function "17.2: Apps that require users to share personal information, such as email address and date of birth, in order to function will be rejected".

Comment: Casar, I want to hear your advice.  My app doesn't force registration to use it for free, but it requires registration to purchase non-renewing subs.  Does apple reject this way?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947324/registration-should-be-always-optional-on-non-renewing-subscription

Comment: Thanks for the point of "buy 2 different products on 2 different devices, register on one of them and then login on the other one"!

Comment: This seems like a tricky problem. If the user is not connected to the iCloud (my app is storing some info about the purchase in the iCloud), and they do not first do a restore on the second device, then how do you relate the two accounts in the database? I guess what must be done is a merging of the two previously separate accounts. I.e., merging of the two previously separate unique_token's. Yikes. That's kind of ugly.

Comment: If you implement restore functionality, as you're required to do, then any purchases should be restored to any device that they use that account on.  Restore functionality doesn't require registering information.