# How to support multiple devices with non-renewing In-App Purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

I'm building an iOS app that will include an IAP with a non-renewing subscription. Apple provides this nugget in their [overview of IAP](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html):

> > You are required to deliver non-renewing subscriptions to all devices owned by the user. Non-renewing subscriptions are not automatically synchronized to all devices by Store Kit; you must implement this infrastructure yourself. For example, most subscriptions are provided by an external server; your server would need to implement a mechanism to identify users and associate subscription purchases with the user who purchased them.

I would like to follow this rule: I want my users to be able to take advantage of the subscription they purchase on one device on other devices as well. So how can I identify the same user across their iPhone and iPad? I understand that you can't use the Apple ID, and you can't rely on a registration method.

I just now found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466392/app-rejected-how-to-track-user-non-renewing-subscription); the answer given there doesn't appear to be workable. There must be something more elegant that others have done.

Comment: So does it mean that when you call [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions] on the device that wasn't used to purchase the subscription originally, you don't get the transaction back?

Comment: For non-renewing subs, that is correct. You have to manage them yourself.

Comment: it's 2023. Is this still the case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a suggestion given to me from [Gavin McKenzie](http://twitter.com/#!/gavinmckenzie), which sounds like the best bet I've heard:

Upon purchase of the subscription, make a "short code" available to the user. The code would be stored on the server as well, tied to that user's account. When they hit Restore on another device, request the short code from the original device and account, thereby tying those devices together.

Gavin further suggested the use of this in a "pairing" method similar to Bluetooth: when restoring, initiate the pairing on Device A, which generates the short code and pushes it to the server. Device B can then use that code. Five minutes later, or when the pairing screen is dismissed, the code is deleted.

I'm not sure how this would stand up if you want to restore to the same device, say, after deleting the phone and restoring. But this feels like a good start.

Comment: Way late to the party here, but I would suspect this might not work --- even if the person loses the code, you're still responsible for restoring the subscription.

Comment: I just happened to check back on this. Yes, I can affirm it works perfectly! My app has been in the store for a month and through two updates, it's been approved. One difference from what I wrote above: I included a user name in addition to the token. Not sure it matters, but better safe than sorry...

Comment: One modification of this method may be to make a unique code (perhaps not so short) that is not available to the user, but is shared across the app and the server. Tell the user that if they want to later do a restore, they need to make an account (username/password). On your server, you can then relate the username/password to the unique code.

Answer (score 0):

If you can drop support for iOS below version 5.0, you could use iCloud to sync a key-value pair across user's devices.

Comment: It's a new app, so I'm comfortable with that. But will Apple accept iCloud as a mechanism for this? And what if they don't have it enabled?

Comment: I don't see any reason for Apple to not accept this. However, if the user has iCloud turned off, then yes, you're out of luck.

Comment: I tried this! Apple didn't like it. I even appealed to the review board (and after a few weeks) they called and said I needed to implement an **optional** username/password system.  What I had done was store a generated, unique identifier in the user's iCloud account (and on my server). When new devices started I'd check for that ID and if it matched a previous user, I'd extend this device the same privileges.  Apple didn't say I wasn't allowed to store the key-value pair, just that I can't do that in the place of an **optional** username password system.

Comment: Wow, that's quite silly of them. Thanks for letting us know about it.

Comment: The WWDC2012 session "Managing Subscriptions with In-App-Purchase" covers this topic in depth and actually prescribes using iCloud as the best mechanism for syncing non-renewing-subscription receipts across devices (around 30:00 into the video).  The presenter says you can OPTIONALLY implement a registration mechanism involving your own server but suggests that this is more work than is necessary, and that iCloud-based syncing is entirely sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

See this:

http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/business-legal-app-store/88698-floored-by-new-rejection.html

Apparently you can require a username/password before purchase. It's really the only way that makes sense. A code can be shared by thousands of people, which is bad.

Comment: As many argue in that thread, requiring registration prior to purchase is a questionable user experience. I prefer my method -- which works great, by the way -- of assigning a per-user token.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Frac.as](http://frac.as/).  It does a variant of the "short code" pairing suggested above, but with some built in smarts to prevent abuse.  It's a SaaS API, with a generous free tier.