# Non Renewable In-App Purchase with Restoration using iCloud

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, in-app-purchase

I am creating an app in which i have an in-app purchase functionality. I am using non-renewable type of subscription but i have to give the support for restoring the subscription in multiple devices.

After going through multiple documents, i found out using iCloud to be the better way to implement it and provide subscription content for user's multiple devices. Finally i decided the following design to be implemented:

> 1. User explores the app
> 2. Clicks on In-App purchase button option
> 3. Check for iCloud availability
>
>    1. iCloud Available :
>
>       1. Continue with the purchase in usual way
>    2. iCloud not available :
>
>       1. Show Alert view : "Sign in to iCloud required to access the subscribed content on your other device", with options "OK" and
>            "Continue anyway"
>
>          1. Click OK :
>
>             1. Remains on the same page
>          2. Click "Continue anyway" :
>
>             1. Continues with the purchase
>             2. If already purchased and iCloud available, update the iCloud receipt
> 4. On successful purchase, we get the transaction receipt. We will store this receipt in the iCloud (One time store in iCloud at the time
>      of purchase) using key value storage and also in the user defaults
> 5. Purchase successful.
> 6. User launches the app from another device
> 7. Check for any transaction receipt in the user defaults. If available, verify and proceed accordingly
> 8. If no receipt available in user defaults, Check for iCloud availability
>
>    1. iCloud Available :
>
>       1. Check if any transaction receipt is available
>       2. If available, verify the receipt. If the receipt is valid, provide subscribed content
>       3. If not available, no action required and proceed normally
>    2. iCloud not available :
>
>       1. Show alert view : "Please sign into your iCloud account to enjoy your subscription content, if any" with options "OK"
>       2. Inside the app, user switches on the option "subscribe to HD addition", will check for his subscription

**ISSUE :**

1. User purchases the app without logging into the iCloud
2. Launches the app from another device
3. He is not able to get the subscribed content

The only way to handle this scenario in a perfect way, considering all the test scenarios, is to store user's iCloud credentials into the user defaults, which i am not sure can be done/is recommended/is allowed. Any kind of suggestion is most welcome.

Also, I would need people's kind views over the above mentioned steps that whether it will be the right way to proceed with or not. Kindly suggest if i can improve it or can have a better way.

Comment: How would storing the user's iCloud credentials into user defaults help you for access to purchases on a different device? (By the way, I wouldn't use user defaults for this, I would use the Key Chain). Also, there is some concern on stackoverflow that Apple will reject a restore method that only uses iCloud (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492898/how-to-support-multiple-devices-with-non-renewing-in-app-purchase/9500185#9500185).

Comment: Accepted, it won't help me storing the credentials into user defaults. I am now going to avoid any scenario i n which i need to think about storing user credentials. I do not find it a right approach. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I made an App that uses iCloud `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`(which has similar selector like `NSUserDefaults`) to sync consumable type of IAP item.
You can check repos on Github like MKiCloudSync to see how it works.

When using `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore`, there's no need for App to know the iDevices' iCloud status.
In my case, if someone holds 2 devices, device 1 has iCloud login but device 2 not, I'll ignore device 2.