# Restore transactions for Non-renewing subscriptions without registration

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

AppStore reviewer requires us to purchase `Non-renewing subscriptions` type will not enforce user to register. He means also the user not register he can also purchase `Non-renewing subscriptions` type

And Apple Document requires `Non-renewing subscriptions` must can be restored.
He said :

> Non-renewing subscriptions and consumable products are not
>   automatically restored by Store Kit. Non-renewing subscriptions must
>   be restorable, however. To restore these products, you must record
>   transactions on your own server when they are purchased and provide
>   your own mechanism to restore those transactions to the user’s
>   devices.

So when user register , I will give the user an unique userId , he can get the userId with his userName and password , so I can share the user's info for different ios device , and I can restore the transactions , because they have an unique userId.

But the problem is this : when the user not register , my server will also give them an unique userId , the non-registration user will save the userId to the `.plist` . They can also restore transactions. But when he delete my app , and then download once , the userId is lost , so he can not restore transactions. He will be a normal default user.

Does the appStore will reject my app for the reason :

> Cannot Restore transactions for Non-renewing subscriptions without registration,which
>   delete the app before restore

If appStore will reject , how to fix it ,thx all.

Comment: I'm concerned about the idea of giving the userId to the user or storing it to the .plist. What if a malicious user posts this userId online? That would break your security, yes? (The .plist info is available through programs such as iExplorer).

Comment: @ChrisPrince He can posts his userId online , but our server has a transactions list . One subscription (which is not used) can be restored successfully only once. If he posts to others , one of others can restore successfully , and he can not restore. So that would not break my security.

Comment: @ChrisPrince Note that : transactions are important. UserId only means restore to whom. Some hackers steal your transactions and then sell the transactions to other users.

Comment: @ChrisPrince My transactions not save in the '.plist' , so I do not think he can break my security

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have submit my app to the appStore.

I restore transactions for Non-renewing subscriptions who register or login.

I do not restore transactions for Non-renewing subscriptions who don't "register" and "delete my app".

My app is approved

Comment: That mean they may accept an app that don't restore purchases if iCloud not logged in. right? what do you think?

Comment: @hasan My app is support iOS4.3+ , so there is no iCloud. And I do not find a perfect way to `restore transactions for Non-renewing subscriptions without registration,which delete the app before restore` I will restore transactions for login users and restore transactions for guest who not delete my app

Comment: This is good to know. I'm following a similar strategy for my app, but haven't yet submitted it.

Answer (score 1):

- Registration must be optional for non-renewable inapp items.
- You can give them a message that if you want to use on multiple devices, then you have to Register and login.
- While registration, personal information like email and mobile no has to be optional and you have to explain them specifically why you have kept email in registeration (e.g like password recovery).
- Just like previous comment, if the inapp for non-renewable item is not so expensive, they can accept the application.  But if, the inapp is costly, they wont allow you to break any of their rules.

Note: You can use a mechanism to use UUID and store it in the keychain. If you reinstall the application, you can get it from keychain again and using the same UUID, you can manage expiry at your server.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Suggests using iCloud to persist the purchase data:

```
#if USE_ICLOUD_STORAGE
NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *storage = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];
#else
NSUserDefaults *storage = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
#endif

NSData *newReceipt = transaction.transactionReceipt;
NSArray *savedReceipts = [storage arrayForKey:@"receipts"];
if (!receipts) {
    // Storing the first receipt
    [storage setObject:@[newReceipt] forKey:@"receipts"];
} else {
    // Adding another receipt
    NSArray *updatedReceipts = [savedReceipts arrayByAddingObject:newReceipt];
    [storage setObject:updatedReceipts forKey:@"receipts"];
}

[storage synchronize];
```

At least it's better than throwing away the purchase information, when the user deletes the app. Making the customer pay twice for a service, is not a great user experience.

Comment: transactionReceipt is deprecated.