# how to prevent users sharing their apple id for in-app-purchase

Tags: ios, transactions, in-app-purchase, non-renewing-subscription

I am implementing an App with in app purchase of type:non-renewing subscriptions.

according to apple documents:

**If your app uses non-renewing subscriptions, your app is responsible for the restoration process.**

[FROM HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html)

My question is, if the restoring is mandatory by apple, how to prevent thousands of users sharing one apple account with only one description?

For example, if in my app, you pay $0.99 that can use this app for 10 days, from apple's requirements, the user must be able to use app within 10 days on any his/her devices, with simply enter the credentials. However, if the user set a simple account credentials and share it with 100 people, then, the 100 people don't have to buy the subscription anymore and can use the app free during the 10 days.

Some people keep assert that people won't share their account... how do you know that? i saw people register some apple id exclusive for sharing apps and games, and only need to pay once.

Besides, i don't implement my own server and my App don't need one. Is there a way to prevent this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Since non-renewing subscriptions seem to require the app (developer) to use a separate (non-Apple) server to deal with the restore process (for example, see [How to support multiple devices with non-renewing In-App Purchase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9492898/how-to-support-multiple-devices-with-non-renewing-in-app-purchase)), why not have that server keep track of the number of restores per "user"? Then you could impose a maximum number of restores per "user". Each installed app that has made a purchase could have its own unique_token (for example, see [app rejected.how to track user non-renewing subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9466392/app-rejected-how-to-track-user-non-renewing-subscription?rq=1)). The user would then have to have a username/password, which would be associated with the unique_token, in order to do a restore (for example, see [Restore transactions for Non-renewing subscriptions without registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17609347/restore-transactions-for-non-renewing-subscriptions-without-registration); and see [Registration should be always optional on non-renewing subscription?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11947324/registration-should-be-always-optional-on-non-renewing-subscription)).